# SQL Query make columns results into rows

Tags: sql, reporting, service

I'm using reporting services to make a report graph. However my data looks like this:

```
Table1
    C01    C02   C03   C04
    1      2     3     4

I need to do a sql query to return data that looks like this:
    Any_Col_name
    1
    2
    3
    4
```

I'm using MS Reporting Services with a Oracle DB. I cannot restructure the table.

Comment: Any table that has C01..C04 is almost certainly not normalized.

Comment: Pax, you're an idiot. He never said he designed the table, just that he's querying it? Go flame somewhere else.

Comment: And how do you know those are the actual column names? More than likely he's just using C## for an example. What crawled up your ass and died?

Comment: @Mark, in a word, no! I have as much right here as you. I just tire of seeing questions about tables that, if they'd been done right, wouldn't have to be asked. If you can't see the problem with that table, then you're NOT a database designer as you state.

Comment: Any query that needs to turn columns into rows is an indication of bad design.

Comment: Please explain why you think this is a result of Max's short sightedness. While you're at it, explain why you felt the urge to comment on the table design when the question is about writing a query.

Comment: PAX,
I didn't design the table. This is an oracle table that someone else made to use with an excel macro to make a excel report. My task is to reproduce this report for the web with reporting services. The column names I used are generic. Its just an example.

Comment: I'm not debating the design. The question isn't about the design. The question is how to write a query. I should be more forgiving, English may not be your first language and the question may have confused you.  The word CANNOT, means unable to, not allowed, verboten. If the OP asked about design...

Comment: @Max, ignore Pax. Obviously he's either a good guy having a bad day or a priggish snob who'd rather flame people than help.

Comment: Because the table design is wrong. If it can't be changed, that's short-sightedness and you'll have to suffer by using sub-optimal SQL. A table change is a one-time cost which can be amortized, sub-optimal queries cost every time you use them.

Comment: @Pax, get over yourself, if you think the answer is "dont design a table like that, the solution for this problem is never required" just post it as an answer.

Comment: That's not what the answer is sambo, because the question states the limitation of not changing the table. Mark has provided a workable answer but comments are for discussion (free and frank, as the politicians would say).

Comment: @pax, again, explain how it is MAX's fault. Again no one is debating the shortsightedness. Why did MAX deserve the comment.

Comment: I've already explained why that was done, Mark, you asked what "crawled up my ass", suggested that English wasn't my first language (a trip to the user page would have told you I was Australian), called me a "priggish snob" and a "dick". All brilliant debating points, but offensive nonetheless.

Comment: Have a look where the first ad hominem attack was...

Comment: But you flagged an answer... not my comments and not me.

Comment: The first ad hominem was when you referred to Max as a wanna-be DBA.

Comment: I've said my piece, there seem to be more people disagreeing than agreeing, so I'll move on. Good luck with your answers, Max, I still don't agree with the way it was done but, as others have clearly pointed out, that's not your fault.

Comment: Ah, nice try at an apology but no soup for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select c01 from table
union all
select c02 from table
union all
select c03 from table
union all
select c04 from table
```

Comment: Why is Mark being downvoted? A union is the correct way to handle this with generic ANSI SQL.

Comment: I didn't vote it down, because it works, hence is helpful. Efficiency is another matter. I *did* flag it offensive because of the language Mark used in his comments - I make no apologies for that.

Comment: Free and frank, huh? You're not flagging me as offensive, nor the comment, you're flagging the post, where there's nothing offensive. but I'm not surprised.

Comment: That's the way I work. My view is that people should be punished for offensive language and that's the only way to do it for offense in comments. Take it up with the site owners and they can reverse it. If they also tell me not to do it again, I'll abide by that. Or raise a uservoice request.

Comment: It's not offensive language, it offended you. Commenting on someone's language skills isn't offensive to the public at large, nor is priggish or snob. Not to mention, there's no "punishment" but to remove the post, a correct answer as you yourself point out. So you think that *I* will be "punished"

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Oracle 11G and above, you can also use unpivot for this, it should be more efficient than the union all (haven't tested this cause I do not have oracle around)

```
SELECT Any_Col_name  FROM table   
    UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS (Any_Col_name FOR Col IN (C01,C02,C03,C04))
```

Comment: He didn't say the Oracle was 11g. Unpivot isn't available until then, unless MSRS will just restructure the query sent to Oracle to gather every row and then apply the SQL Server syntax to that result set. Not sure how that will work.

Comment: @Mark, I edited the answer to reflect. MSRS will not do anything funky to the queries.

Comment: Kewl... Always a good idea to give the latest and greatest as an option... tease people with what they could have if only.

Comment: This is the best answer as long as UNPIVOT is supported.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175574

It describes how to "rotate" a table in SQL Server. I know you said Oracle buy you might glean something from it.

Comment: That's the wrong direction. it's already flat and he wants it vertical.

Comment: I found another answer of yours to mod +1... no hard feelings.

Answer (score 0):

We have solved this problem many times. Your best plan of action is to write appropriate PL/SQL functions that will iterate through all of the columns, outputting them as rows. I say to do it this way, because this will probably not be the last time you use this functionality.