# sql query to set data as column heading

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have a problem that is deceptively difficult! Lets say I have a DB table that looks like this:

```
student_id  score
502         0
502         2
502         4
407         3
407         1
407         3
50          2
50          4
50          3
```

What I am trying to achieve is a select statement that will give me this:

```
502  407   50
0    3     2
2    1     4
4    3     3
```

So I would be doing something like a select distinct on student_id and set those as column headings. Then I want to list all the scores for each distinct student_id.

Comment: You are looking for a PIVOT operation.   Not sure how to do it in mySQL...

Comment: It's about pivot and unpivoting, you can find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567655/sql-query-make-columns-results-into-rows more info

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+pivot

Comment: possible duplicate of [Postgresql pivot? Crosstab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329041/postgresql-pivot-crosstab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will put this to rest and say it is not possible to do this in a single sql statement where the statement produces the column headings (in this case student_id) based on what is in the table. It seems you really do need the power of a full programming language to accomplish the task.

The end goal for me is a CSV so I will create a CSV from the table data and then write a ruby script to read the cells and create a new CSV with the column headings and data.